# I can't move the mouse after installing Windows 7

Tags: windows, mouse, drivers

I can't move the mouse, even though it was working in the Windows 7 setup process.  I'm using a Toshiba Satellite P-305-S8820.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Is the mouse plugged in? Turned on? Do you need to install mouse drivers?

Comment: it's the touchpad not working even though I updated the driver

Comment: @Peter: Was it working before you updated the driver?

Comment: no it wasn't it, now I turn the laptop off may times until it works and then when i restart it stops working again